# Is there a builtin "hash to string" in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, hash

I'm coming to learn Perl from a Python background where the following hash-to-string conversion is built in to the language:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> str(d)
"{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}"
```

Is there a builtin and/or module that has a subroutine with output along the lines of:

```
"('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3)"
```

Strangely, a web search for `perl "hash to string"` doesn't turn up anything along the lines I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
my $str = Dumper({a => 1, b => 2, c => 3});
```

Answer (score 31):

See also [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
use JSON;

my $data = {a => 1, b=> 2, c => 3};

print to_json($data);
```

This produces:

```
{"c":3,"a":1,"b":2}
```

Comment: +1 While it seems Data::Dumper was voted answer, I think the JSON approach deserves as much recognition for a very simple hash to string.

Comment: Though the original question doesn't imply this is a concern, JSON::to_json is _fast_, so if you're needing to serialise a lot of things, this could be a significantly better answer than Data::Dumper. ( http://doppnet.com/2011/03/how-to-gain-24861-performance-boost-in-perl/ )

Comment: Thanks, I should be using JSON more anyway.  Of course, on MacOS it wasn't installed, so first "cpan install JSON", thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382371/446767

Answer (score 11):

There is the [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper/) module which one way to do this sort of transformation.

Comment: Yes, but it does prepend a `$VAR1 = ` before the string.

Comment: That's true, annoying but tractable.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dump/) instead of Data::Dumper.  It's basically the same, except without that annoying `$VAR1 = ...` cruft:

```
use Data::Dump "pp";
print pp({a => 1, b => 2, c => 3});
```

Produces:

```
{ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 }
```

If you're on Windows, Data::Dump has come pre-installed with [ActivePerl](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Downloads/ActivePerl/) since version 5.8.

Comment: Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC - it is not standard library.

Comment: On ActivePerl 5.10, build 1004, Data::Dump 1.08 came pre-installed.

Comment: +1, I hadn't realized this module exists BTW.  It lacks certain add-ons like HTML formatting, but oh well.

Comment: Kev: Are you saying that good ol' Data::Dumper can produce HTML-formatted output?  If so that's pretty cool...

Answer (score 2):

Yet Another Swallow Solution:

```
sub pp {
  my $h = shift();
  qq[{${\(join',',map"$_=>$h->{$_}",keys%$h)}}]
}
print pp({a => 1, b => 2, c => 3});
```

But use [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper/Dumper.pm) instead.

For very fancy output you can use also:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Perl::Tidy;
sub pp {
        local $Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;
        local $Data::Dumper::Indent   = 0;
        my $source = Dumper(@_);
        my $result;
        Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
                source      => \$source,
                destination => \$result,
                argv        => [qw(-pbp -nst)]
        );
        return $result;
}
```

If you prefer some keys should be first than you can use this approach (i want `type` first and `position` second):

```
    local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = sub {
            [   sort {
                            if    ( $b eq 'type' )     {1}
                            elsif ( $a eq 'type' )     {-1}
                            elsif ( $b eq 'position' ) {1}
                            elsif ( $a eq 'position' ) {-1}
                            else                       { $a cmp $b }
                            } keys %{ $_[0] }
            ];
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Several of the above solutions have a problem if you have the potential for multi-level structures.

Specifically this flag:

```
$Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;
```

As noted on the perldoc page for Data::Dumper, the "terse" flag could generate non-perl parseable output.

If you possibly are going to have multi-depth structures the proper thing to do would be to instead use:

```
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
```

Which is guaranteed to be perl parseable by eval, which makes for a very very easy way of doing serialization to plaintext...