# How to install JSON.pm perl module on OSX

Tags: macos, perl, perl-module

I am trying to use the po2json parser/converter from the JS gettext library (http://jsgettext.berlios.de/), but when I try to convert I get this error:

```
Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at ./po2json line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./po2json line 23.
```

As far as I understand I am missing a perl module, namely JSON.pm, an I think it's this one: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm

Now, how do I install it on OSX? I am using Mountain Lion.

I tried to do `cpan install JSON`, but it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
Writing Makefile for JSON
  MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.53.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output said that `make` didn't return success. Probably due to some dependency.
Try using cpanm http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.5017/bin/cpanm, it's really hassle free and bootstrapped quite well (no need to install other stuff).

Install using this:

`curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus`

Comment: I tried to install using your command, but got this error: `! Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See /Users/ragulka/.cpanm/build.log for details.`

The log file has this:

`Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.31 ... Yes (6.56)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... Yes (0.3603)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 1.46 ... Yes (1.55)
-> FAIL Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'.`

Comment: Do you have `make` installed? You'll need it to install perl modules.

Comment: Found it :) On Mac OS X those command line tools come with the Apple developer tools. You can get those at their site http://developer.apple.com/

Comment: Thnaks, I'll install them and see what happens then :)

Comment: I installed XCode (Developer Tools) and tried running cpanm, it wasnät found, tried to run your install command, and it still did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I had to Open Developer Tools, go to Preferences -> Downloads and then install Command Line Tools. After that, I just had to do "sudo cpan App::cpanminus" in my Terminal

Comment: You need the XCode [command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (Apple really make this a pain).

Answer (score 38):

Use [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) to install cpanm:

`brew install cpanm`

Then you can install JSON with

`sudo cpanm install JSON`

Comment: This is the cleanest (and hassle free) solution if you're using homebrew :)

Comment: `cpanm install JSON` (without the `sudo`) worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

`cpan install JSON` Having the JSON in all caps made it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic, but wanted to share my solution after finding that I needed JSON when trying to use zap2xml (perl based). I was getting the error: "*Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC...*" after installing perl via Homebrew.

This is how I installed JSON via Homebrew. I will also include the steps required to install Homebrew (for those who would like to know). ;)

**Prerequisites:**

**Install Xcode from the App Store (Download):**

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835

**Install Command Line Tools for Xcode (Run in Terminal):**

`xcode-select --install`

**Install Homebrew (Run in Terminal):**

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

**Update Homebrew (Run in Terminal):**

`brew update`

`brew upgrade`

`brew doctor` (correct issues found by brew doctor. Instructions will be given by The Doctor. :P)

**Install cpanminus (Run in Terminal):**

`brew install cpanm`

**Check perl (Run in Terminal):**

`which perl`

`perl -V` (with a capital -V)

**Check/Install JSON module (Run in Terminal):**

`sudo cpanm -v JSON`

**DONE.**

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me:
Run on terminal:
`sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell`

you should get the cpan shell prompt and run below commond at cpan shell:

```
cpan[1]> install JSON
```

Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score -4):

this way is OK, Follows the Command:`sudo apt-get install libjson-perl`

Comment: Mac OS X does not have `apt-get`.